# Can a circle be mapped to a line such that the line does not pass through the centre of the circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I have been looking at Mobius transformations in an attempt to map a circle to a straight line.

In all the examples I have seen however, the resulting straight line intersects the circle through its centre.

Is it possible to transform the circle in such a way that the straight line does not pass through the centre?

More specifically, is it possible to transform the circle such that the resulting straight line is tangential to the original circle? That is to say the straight line is a distance ***r*** (the radius of the circle) from the centre?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done. For instance, the Möbius transformation
$$
f(z) = \frac{2z}{z + 1}
$$
sends the unit circle to the vertical line going through $1$.

More generally, given any three distinct points $z_1, z_2, z_3$ and any other triplet of distinct points $w_1, w_2, w_3$ (where up to one of the $z_i$ and up to one of the $w_i$ may be $\infty$), there is exactly one Möbius transformation $g$ with $g(z_i) = w_i$ for all $i$. Consequently, $g$ will map the generalized circle defined by the $z_i$ to the generalized circle defined by the $w_i$ (where "generalized circle" means a circle, unless the three points are collinear or one of them is at infinity, in which case "generalized circle" means a line).